# Flutter Align: not working for multiple line text

Tags: flutter

Flutter Align right: not align right for multiple line text.

```
       SizedBox(
              width: 108,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                    child: Text('Billing Address:'),
                  )),
            );
```

When the text "Billing Address:" is rendered as two lines, it is aligned left, not right.

```
---------------
Billing       |
Address:      |
---------------
```

It works for one line, e.g., "Name:"

```
---------------
        Name: |
---------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Name:" case, the `Text` widget takes only the required width for its text to fit, so it looks correctly aligned to the top-right of the parent widget.

In the "Billing Address:" case, the `Text` widget has its size reached the maximum width available, so it's actually aligned to the top-right correctly by the `Align` widget. However, the internal text itself is still aligned to the start (left, in [LTR direction](https://m2.material.io/design/usability/bidirectionality.html)) by default.

You have to align the text inside the `Text` widget itself, by setting the `textAlign` to `TextAlign.end` (when using LTR direction):

```dart
Text(
  // ...
  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
)
```